# Local Variables declared inside a function awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am using awk. I would like to modularize my code and I would like to know whether variables declared inside a function is a local or global.. For instance

```
  main script
  update()

  function update()
  {
      array[1]="hi"
  }
```

I would like to know whether the array which is declared inside the function is a local or a global .. If it is not local then.. what is the concept of local variable in awk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are global:

```
awk 'function update() { array[1]="hi" } BEGIN { update(); print array[1];}'
hi
```

To make it local, you need a little trick, pass it as an argument:

```
awk 'function update(array) { array[1]="hi" } BEGIN { update(); print array[1];}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. what is I pass update(array) while calling itself. Now will the array be global or local

Comment: to make it local you don't pass anything, as in the example. if you pass the same thing you received it's going to be shared, but still not global to the whole code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ..So can I conclude like, update(array) when being passed will be global and to make it local we can declare without passsing and the array would be destroyed when it goes out of the function...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, it's better if you do some tests

Comment: Yes I have done the research what u said is correct ... Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: To be more precise, you should say "declare it as an argument without passing the argument when the function is called. Also, you can have multiple declared arguments and pass values for some of the first ones and not for the rest. The latter ones will be treated as local. The convention is to separate the arguments in the declaration with extra spaces to visually distinguish the actual arguments from the local ones: `function foo(arg1, arg2,____________arg3, arg4)` (the underscores here represent extra spaces since the site eats them)